# AsyncTask not working and im not sure why

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

so i am trying to have a button create a repeating action and i found a little bit of code that suggested do it this way and i am not getting any errors in eclipse but when i run the app and press the button it forces close, i am not sure if you need my log-cat but if you do please tell me and ill post it.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    class MyAsyncTask extends android.os.AsyncTask {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                        int upCounter = 0;
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(700);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        upCounter++;
                        Money = Money+5;
                        MoneyDis.setText("$"+Money);

                        return null;
                    }
                }

    UpGradeRep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            (new MyAsyncTask()).execute();

        }
    });
```

Comment: may I know what you are really trying to accomplish?

Comment: im trying to make it so when the user pushes the button it starts counting up untill it gets to 100, wall at the same ti,me the user can still click other buttons and stuff hope that helps

Comment: you cannot handle UI related work in background thread you must use your .setText methhod in onProgressUpdate method then only your issue will get resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MoneyDis.setText("$"+Money);
```

is definitely wrong. You have to call this in UI thread.
Move it to:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(int Money) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MoneyDis.setText("$"+Money);
        }
```

Learn the some code provided by Google:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: ok, that was the problem, so how would i do MoneyDis.setText("$"+Money) every time it goes threw the code? so that it has a counting up effect?

Comment: @jason flanagan I've edited my answer. Take a look.You can update it in onProgressUpdate

Comment: ok, lol im gana try to understand it, it looks vary intimadateing lol,im vary new to java so im not vary good at understanding this stuff, but ill read about it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Internally `setText` will check if current thread is *main/UI thread* and it will throw an exception if not. Apparently, `doInBackground` is running in a child thread which will elicits that exception

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Views present on the activity in  `doInBackground()` as it works on the background thread. Try getting the reference of the activity by using `WeakReference`
or override `onProgressUpdate()`,change the `textView` contents in that, and simply call `publishProgress(counter)` each time you want to update the `textView`